# Copy a template_file to the created instance

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I create a template_file but then I want to copy this to a certain place on the newly created instance?

I managed to do it by creating a bash script with a multiline string/EOF tag which the formatted list of private ips gets substituted into and which gets copied, but is there a neater (perhaps a terraform native) way?

(The exact thing I'm doing here is creating an nginx load balancer which send to proxy instances, and the private ips of these instances need to go inside the nginx config.)

**Terraform Code:**

```
locals {
  private_ips = formatlist("172.31.1.%s", range(var.n_proxies))
}

resource "aws_instance" "proxies" {
  count           = var.n_proxies
  ami             = "ami-07cffef981d804d48"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.instance_sg.id]
  tags = {
    "Name"   = "Proxy"
    "Number" = count.index + 1
  }
  private_ip = local.private_ips[count.index]
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.public_zone.id
  key_name                    = "mykey"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  root_block_device {
    volume_type = "gp3"
    volume_size = 8
  }
}

data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = <<DOC
#!/bin/bash

cat > /etc/nginx/modules-available/load_balancer.conf <<EOF
stream {
        upstream backend {
$${servers}
        }

        server {
                listen 3128;
                proxy_pass backend;
        }
}
EOF

sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/modules-available/load_balancer.conf /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/load_balancer.conf

sudo systemctl restart nginx
DOC

  vars = {
    servers      = "${join("", formatlist("\n            server %s:3128;", local.private_ips))}"
  }

  depends_on = [local.private_ips]
}

resource "aws_instance" "pump_bot_lb" {
  ami             = "ami-06bfba6e971885cbd"
  instance_type   = "a1.medium"
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.lb_sg.id]
  tags = {
    "Name"   = "LB"
  }
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.public_zone.id
  key_name                    = "mykey"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  root_block_device {
    volume_type = "gp3"
    volume_size = 8
  }
  user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Is there any terraform code you are using?

Comment: @MarkoE I just updated the question which what I have successfully done